# Raster data type as input in processing algorithms

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Why the processing algorithms run just with input files located in QGIS desktop? Is there any way to work with directories?

I am developing a plugin and I am using processing algorithms but the number of input files doesn't give the possibility to work in QGIS desktop. Is there any way to work with directories?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you mean by "Desktop" ? If you can select files as input the user can choose to load sth. from the Desktop in Windows as well.
For Directories:
You could enable the option for users to load a custom folder as string parameter:

```
self.addParameter(ParameterString(self.DIR, 'Lookup Directory','C:/' ))
```

In any simple script you can use

```
##directory=folder
```

Comment: I think he/she is talking about **QGIS** Desktop. The processing algorithms usually work with layers that are loaded in QGIS.

Comment: Yes. I am talking about QGIS desktop. I am trouble to run processing algorithms in python script because I have as input file a hdf file (modis image).                                           My code to call processing algorithm is: Processing.runAlgorithm("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent", None, raster_path, None, "x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max", None, out_clip_ndvi). The raster_path is a hdf file. But it gives me an error because a hdf file have several datasets but I don't know how to input them.

Comment: You could use gdal_translate to extract them temporarily: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90352/convert-800-hdf4-files-to-tiff-using-grass-qgis-saga-gdal-r

Comment: @user27513: Then you should edit your question (especially the title). The answer to your question does not depend on processing, but on your raster datatype and the way gdal works

Comment: How I can use gdal_translate in a plugin implementation? I see the http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90352/convert-800-hdf4-files-to-tiff-using-grass-qgis-saga-gdal-r answer, and I try but I still have not convert hdf to tiff.

Comment: us the python modules `os` or `subprocess`. For instance `os.system('gdal_translate ..')`

Comment: I try with that too. But doesn't create any raster. I don't know what I am doing wrong.